# How to change the validation of form fields in java script

Tags: javascript

I have a ready-made form for sending messages to the mail, here is a link to github:[validation and sending messages to the mail](https://github.com/Amadu-A/validation)
For validation I use [The old version of validation v 1.5](https://github.com/horprogs/Just-validate/tree/v1)

Please help with the validation of the fields. The problem is this:

1. When validating a field named line 78 of the scripts file.js doesn't work. There is a limit for the name field of 7 characters, but validation uses its own internal rules for a minimum of 2 characters.
2. The phone validation log does not output a log from the 85th line of the file scripts.js , although in theory it should print the phone number without spaces, hyphens and brackets
3. Phone validation does not occur (lines 81-88 of the file scripts.js ). I specified the data-validate-field field with the value tel and specified a function that would return true for this tel. But this rule doesn't work either.

Why doesn't this particular part of the code work?

```
validateForms('.form', {
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 7,
        maxLength: 30,
      },
      tel: {
        tel: true,
        function: (name, value) => {
          const phone = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"]').inputmask.unmaskedvalue()
          console.log(phone)
          return Number(phone) && phone.length === 10
        }
      },
      email: {required: true, email: true},

    },
  }, messages, '.thanks-popup', 'send goal');
```

Please help me solve 3 problems.
HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="admin_email[]" value="any@mail.ru">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Тема письма">
            <h2>Отправка формы</h2>
            <label class="form-label">
                <span>Введите имя</span>
                <input type="text" data-validate-field="name" name="name" required>
            </label>
            <label class="form-label">
                <span>Введите телефон</span>
                <input type="tel" data-validate-field="tel" name="tel" required>
            </label>
            <label class="form-label">
                <span>Введите email</span>
                <input type="email" data-validate-field="email" name="email" required>
            </label>
            <label class="form-label file-label">
                <span>Прикрепить файл</span>
                <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
        </form>
        <script src="inputmask.min.js"></script>
        <script src="just-validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

File code script.js

```
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="tel"]');
let im = new Inputmask('+7 (999) 999-99-99');
im.mask(selector);

let selector2 = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"]');

selector2.addEventListener('input', function(){
    console.log(selector2.value)


    const re = /^\d*(\.\d+)?$/

    console.log(selector2.value.match(/[0-9]/g).length)


    console.log(selector2.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, "0"));
    
});

const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let files = e.currentTarget.files;
    console.log(files);

    if (files.length) {
        fileInput.closest('label').querySelector('span').textContent = files[0].name;
    } else {
        fileInput.closest('label').querySelector('span').textContent = 'Прикрепить файл';
    }

});

let validateForms = function(selector, rules, messages, successModal, yaGoal) {
    new window.JustValidate(selector, {
        rules: rules,
        messages: messages,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            let formData = new FormData(form);

            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log('Отправлено');
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.open('POST', 'mail.php', true);
            xhr.send(formData);

            form.reset();

            fileInput.closest('label').querySelector('span').textContent = 'Прикрепить файл';
        }
    });
}

// validateForms('.form', { email: {required: true, email: true}, tel: {required: true} }, '.thanks-popup', 'send goal');
let messages = {
    name: {
      required: "Вы не ввели имя",
      minLength: "Имя должно иметь более 3 символов",
      maxLength: "Имя должно быть менее 30 символов",
    },
    tel: {
      required: "Неверный формат номера",
      tel: "Введите телефон",
    },
}

  validateForms('.form', {
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 7,
        maxLength: 30,
      },
      tel: {
        tel: true,
        function: (name, value) => {
          const phone = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"]').inputmask.unmaskedvalue()
          console.log(phone)
          return Number(phone) && phone.length === 10
        }
      },
      email: {required: true, email: true},

    },
  }, messages, '.thanks-popup', 'send goal');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAfEA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

74 file line script.js should be changed to `new JustValidate('.form', {`
The entire file code will look like

```
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="tel"]');
let im = new Inputmask('+7 (999) 999-99-99');
im.mask(selector);

let selector2 = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"]');

selector2.addEventListener('input', function(){
    console.log(selector2.value)


    const re = /^\d*(\.\d+)?$/

    console.log(selector2.value.match(/[0-9]/g).length)


    console.log(selector2.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, "0"));
    
});

const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let files = e.currentTarget.files;
    console.log(files);

    if (files.length) {
        fileInput.closest('label').querySelector('span').textContent = files[0].name;
    } else {
        fileInput.closest('label').querySelector('span').textContent = 'Прикрепить файл';
    }

});

let validateForms = function(selector, rules, messages, successModal, yaGoal) {
    new window.JustValidate(selector, {
        rules: rules,
        messages: messages,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            let formData = new FormData(form);

            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log('Отправлено');
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.open('POST', 'mail.php', true);
            xhr.send(formData);

            form.reset();

            fileInput.closest('label').querySelector('span').textContent = 'Прикрепить файл';
        }
    });
}

// validateForms('.form', { email: {required: true, email: true}, tel: {required: true} }, '.thanks-popup', 'send goal');
let messages = {
    name: {
      required: "Вы не ввели имя",
      minLength: "Имя должно иметь более 3 символов",
      maxLength: "Имя должно быть менее 30 символов",
    },
    tel: {
      required: "Неверный формат номера",
      tel: "Введите телефон",
    },
}

new JustValidate('.form', {
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 7,
        maxLength: 30,
      },
      tel: {
        tel: true,
        function: (name, value) => {
          const phone = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"]').inputmask.unmaskedvalue()
          console.log(phone)
          return Number(phone) && phone.length === 10
        }
      },
      email: {required: true, email: true},

    },
}, messages, '.thanks-popup', 'send goal');
```